# How do you check if the time exist in two array if they do disable them from option

Tags: php, html, arrays, date, int

I am trying to disable an option if the time exist

I wasn't sure which is the correct way to go ahead 
every time I do any check as in 
array_key_exists
array_merge 
implode

i was getting these errors:
date() expects parameter 2 to be integer array given
Expected type 'array'. Found 'int|float'

```
$notAvailable = ["9:00", "9:15", "09:30"];

    // Header
    echo '<select name="time" class="time">';

    $start = strtotime('09:00');
    $end = strtotime('18:00');
    for ($calltime = $start; $calltime <= $end; $calltime = $calltime + 15 * 60) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', date('H:i', $calltime), date('g:i a', $calltime));
    }
    // disabled="disabaled
    echo '</select>';


$notAvailable = ["9:00", "9:15", "09:30"];

$start = strtotime('09:00');
$end = strtotime('18:00');
```

If the `["9:00", "9:15", "09:30"]` match with the loop i want to disable the option to pick

If i do

```
for ($calltime = $start; $calltime <= $end; $calltime = $calltime + 15 * 60) { if ($notAvailable == $calltime) { # code... printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', date('H:i', $calltime), date('g:i a', $calltime)); } }

$result = array_merge($calltime, $notAvailable); if ($result) { # code... printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', date('H:i', $calltime), date('g:i a', $calltime)); }
```

Comment: Running the code given does not produce any errors for me.

Comment: @PatrickQ how did you check $notAvailable this is where my issue is 
in the for loop if i add if statement to check $notAvailable and $calltime i get errors

Comment: I ran code exactly as provided.  If this is not the code that produces errors for you, please provide that code.  Showing us code that isn't causing you problems doesn't help anyone.

Comment: for ($calltime = $start; $calltime <= $end; $calltime = $calltime + 15 * 60) {
            if ($notAvailable == $calltime) {
                # code...
                printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', date('H:i', $calltime), date('g:i a', $calltime));
            }
        }

If i do this i get nothing as results

Comment: $result = array_merge($calltime, $notAvailable);
            if ($result) {
                # code...
                printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', date('H:i', $calltime), date('g:i a', $calltime));
            }
if i do this 'Expected type 'array'. Found 'int|float''

i have said the issue on the question i believe

Comment: Please edit/update your question with the relevant code.  It is near impossible to read code in comments.

Comment: `$notAvailable == $calltime` you are trying to check array == int/float? maybe you are lookin for in_array php function?

Answer (score 2):

You can do below modification and then you'r good to go,

**Modify 1**: `$notAvailable` variable with preceding zero(`0`) value because your for loop generates time values like "**0**9:00", "**0**9:15", "**0**9:30" not "9:00", "9:15", "09:30"

**Modify 2**: Do a check with `in_array()` function if it's index the array then set the `disabled="disabled"` on the **option** else use it simply.

**Modify 3**: assign the time value to a variable to look it more cleaner.(**optional**)

```
<?php
// Header
$notAvailable = ["09:00", "09:15", "09:30"];
echo '<select name="time" class="time">';
$start = strtotime('09:00');
$end = strtotime('18:00');
for ($calltime = $start; $calltime <= $end; $calltime = $calltime + 15 * 60) {
    $time = date('H:i', $calltime);
    $time_with_am_pm = date('g:i a', $calltime);
    if(in_array($time,$notAvailable)){
        printf('<option value="%s" disabled="disabled">%s</option>', $time,$time_with_am_pm);
    }else{
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $time,$time_with_am_pm);
    }   
}
// disabled="disabaled
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: You should probably explain your code so that OP actually understands and learns, instead of just relying on copy/paste.

Comment: @jibingeorge  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253163/1505169  (In this case, _you_)

Comment: @AlwaysSunny I have one more question
so the $notAvailable is just today's time how do i check that like for an example if i click tomorrows date i dont want the time to be disabled is that possible

Comment: @Always Sunny I have a question about this, Is it possible to hide 4 hours ahead from current time when i click the options?

Comment: Yeah it should be possible,  in that case you can add another condition inside your if